# Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: apex

I'm trying to complete a some test code and am running into the 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature' error.

I have a data factory class that generates some test records for other test classes.

```
   @isTest
    public class ABCTestDataFactory {
        public static ABC_Store__c createOneStore(String storeName) {
            ABC_Store__c s = new ABC_Store__c();
            s.Name = storeName;
            insert s;

            return s;
        }

            //other similar methods
     }
```

When referencing the createOneStore() method in this class from my test method I'm receiving the error...what am I doing wrong here?

```
@isTest
private class TestUpdateStageInformation {

    static testMethod void TestUpdateOneStageProbability() {
        //create the objects required before creating an opportunity
        ABC_Store__c s = ABC_TestDataFactory.createOneStore('The Test Store 1'); //this is where the error is happening
        ABC_Account__c account = ABC_TestDataFactory.createOneAccount('99999999999', 'TestLastName', TRUE, s.ID);

        Test.startTest();
                   //tests
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

This is all created in a Developer Org.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your declaration in the first block is ABCTestDataFactory, whereas when you're using it , it's ABC_TestDataFactory (with an underscore)

Unless its a typo in your post, that would be the reason?

Comment: Ahhh thank you!  Been staring at it too long and sometimes, I just need a sanity check.  Silly mistake...

Comment: We can all do with an extra pair of eyes at times :)

Comment: very good catch.